# How to create an rpm out of sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, rpm

I have a script named post_install.sh and it is present in src/main/scripts/post_install.sh. My sbt file is

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmPlugin.autoImport.RpmConstants._
maintainerScripts in Rpm := maintainerScriptsAppendFromFile((maintainerScripts in Rpm).value)(
  Post -> (baseDirectory.value / "scripts" / "install" / "post-install.sh")
)
```

When I run sbt rpm:packageBin I get the following error

[error] (rpm:maintainerScripts) The maintainer script post doesn't exist here: /Users/spachari/IdeaProjects/aws-customer-email-change-history/scripts/install/post-install.sh

Please tell me how do you create an rpm from sbt package.

Comment: @user8371915, thanks for your help. I am still getting the same error after changing the location to /Users/spachari/IdeaProjects/aws-customer-email-change-history/scripts/install/post-install.sh. Plus the script only has echo command for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your error it seems that your `baseDirectory` is `/Users/spachari/IdeaProjects/aws-customer-email-change-history` and the script is really at `/Users/spachari/IdeaProjects/aws-customer-email-change-history/src/main/scripts/post_install.sh`. So you may try to change your code to

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.rpm.RpmPlugin.autoImport.RpmConstants._
maintainerScripts in Rpm := maintainerScriptsAppendFromFile((maintainerScripts in Rpm).value)(
  Post -> (baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main" / "scripts" / "post-install.sh")
)
```

assuming that the script located at the directory works correctly from it.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am still getting the same error after changing the location to /Users/spachari/IdeaProjects/aws-customer-email-change-histo‌​ry/scripts/install/p‌​ost-install.sh. Plus the script only has echo command for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but the following sbt plugin can create rpm without using platform dependent external tools.
Have a look at this github project :
https://github.com/en-vee/sbt-rpm/blob/master/README.md